# Figure in the Chapter

Tags: graphics, sectioning, chapters, koma-script

How can I put an image together with the chapter style in scrbook class (chaptername, chapternumber capitalized - left aligned -, and a figure above them, centered, like the scheme below)?

```
                                   figure

                                         chaptername chapertnumber
```

Comment: what should be left aligned? The figure or the title

Answer (score 5):

There's a macro `\chapterheadstartvskip` which can be used for producing vertical space before the chapter heading. You could redefine that macro to include an image besides making just space. For example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\let\oldchapterheadstartvskip\chapterheadstartvskip
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{%
    \oldchapterheadstartvskip%
    {\centering\includegraphics{image}\par}
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want different images above the chapter heading of different chapters simply use `\chapterpreamble`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=.25\textheight plus 1\baselineskip]{chapter}
\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble[o]{\includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image-a}\bigskip}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\setchapterpreamble[o]{\centerline{\includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image-b}}\bigskip}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\end{document}
```

I have used `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to get more space before the chapter headings.